# Dictionary values to Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dictionary, where the key is a unique integer and the value is a dataframe row.

I want to take all the values (rows) from my dictionary and turn it into an actual dataframe. The structure of one row looks like this.

```
{1: {'imuid': '1192',
     'usid': 63,
     'usme': 'de'}, 
 2: {etc etc}
}
```

I can't quite work out which pandas function to use. I've tried `from_records` but that produces the error `TypeError: object of type 'builtin_function_or_method' has no len()`.

I don't care about the iteration ID, just need the values in the dictionary to be a row. So the dataframe will have multiple rows where the columns are `imuid`, `usid` and `usme`.

Using pandas and python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pd.DataFrame.from_dict` ?

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(<your_dict>, orient='index')
```

Example:

```
d = {1: {'imuid': '1192',
     'usid': 63,
     'usme': 'de'}}

# convert dict to dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index')
```

Output:

```
>       imuid   usid usme
>     1 1192    63  de
```

Comment: `df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(main_dict.values(), orient='index')` causes `AttributeError: 'dict_values' object has no attribute 'values'` so that doesn't work

Comment: the error was caused by `main_dict.values()`, not by my solution.

Comment: Your solution does not work on dictionary.values() which is what I posted with the example of what it is...

Comment: It seems that `main_dict.values()` is `dictionary.values().values()`. So, it's not unusual to have the error `AttributeError: 'dict_values' object has no attribute 'values'`. Why don't you just throw the entire dict into `pd.DataFrame.from_dict` ??

Comment: See my example. It's just that. why `.values()` ??

Comment: thanks :) this seemed obvious but wasn't sure if I could do this! Thanks!

Comment: No problem. Happy to help. @caasswa